# Is it possible to cast an int[][] to an int?

Tags: java

I think I need to cast an int[][] into an int in order to make my code work, but I'm not sure. So is it possible?

For example:

```
public static int[][] multiplyByScalar(int scalar, int[][] matrix)
{
 if (!atLeastOneByOne(matrix))
              throw new IllegalArgumentException();
int result=0;
if(matrix.length==matrix[0].length)
{
 for(int x=0;x<matrix.length;x++)
{
  for(int y=0;y<matrix[x].length;y++)
  {
    result=scalar*matrix[x][y];
  }
}
}
return result; 
}
```

Is this even possible?

*Here is all of the code*

Comment: What error code are you getting? It looks like this should work without any cast - your `matrix[x][y]` accesses only the value of the matrix at [x][y], so it is a single int value. (Assuming matrix is of `int` type)

Comment: What type is `result`? It looks like `matrix[x][y] = result;` should work.

Comment: @RogielSulzbach makes a good point - if you want result to take the value of the variable `matrix` at point `matrix[x][y]`, then you'll likely need `result =matrix [x][y];`

Comment: result is also an int. It is saying unexpected type. It's in Java.

Comment: Oh ok I put the result at the beginning and it worked, but when I try to return result it still says "incompatible types"

Comment: You want to set `result` as the product of `scalar` times `matrix[x][y]`. That's it?

Comment: Please post more of your function, and explain the whole thing you're trying to do. Maybe slow down and think about what you're doing.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Java, but if this is within a function and you can't `return result;` then check your function is of type `int`?

Comment: I think your statement is just the wrong way round. It would be result=.......

Comment: The code in the question is nonsense as written, the assignment is backwards at best. No one can answer this question as formulated.

Comment: What type is your method declared to return, and what is the return value supposed to mean? I suspect you've declared it to return `int[][]` when you want to return an `int`.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't have the foggiest idea what you're doing.

Comment: I assume your phrasing / understanding of casting is a bit off. If `matrix` is an `int[][]` and you simply want to get the `x,y`-th element, that's not casting at all.

Comment: If matrix is an in [][] this should already work. What exception do you get?

Comment: Could you post the entire method

Comment: This is now answerable and im sure rogiel will do a good job of it. For future reference always post at least a complete method. Usually a complete **short** program leads to immediate answers

Answer (score 1):

Since you edited your question, I am editing this answer.

If you look closely to your return type, it is of type `int[][]` while `result` (which is returned) is of type `int`. `int` cannot be casted to `int[][]`.

Return type should be `int` as follows:

```
public static int multiplyByScalar(int scalar, int[][] matrix)
{
 if (!atLeastOneByOne(matrix))
              throw new IllegalArgumentException();
int result=0;
if(matrix.length==matrix[0].length)
{
 for(int x=0;x<matrix.length;x++)
{
  for(int y=0;y<matrix[x].length;y++)
  {
    result=scalar*matrix[x][y];
  }
}
}
return result; 
}
```

Now, looking at what the naming of your method means, you want to multiply a matrix by a scalar, which by definition, returns a matrix. In that case, you need to define `result` as `int[][]` and when you perform actual calculation do it on the same index, like this:

```
public static int[][] multiplyByScalar(int scalar, int[][] matrix) {
    int[][] result = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
    if (matrix.length == matrix[0].length) {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++) {
                result[x][y] = scalar * matrix[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Oh ok I see! Thanks, but it still says result is an incompatible type when I try returning it.

Comment: What's `matrix` type declaration? It should be int[][].

Comment: Congratulations you've been bitten by a chameleon question (as was I). Its changed while we were typing our answers

Comment: It's int[][] and scalar is int

Comment: Sorry i'm new to asking on here I don't really know how to ask things.

Comment: Now I get it... editing answer.

Comment: Oh ok I see!! So that means that int result needs to be changed to int[][] result?

Comment: @user3200599 indeed, and created piece by piece and the  returned only at the end

Comment: Alright. Thank you everyone! Sorry it was such a bad question!!

Comment: Yes, you still need to allocate a `result` array as large as `matrix`, otherwise it will overflow.

Comment: @RogielSulzbach Sorry me again...So would this be ok to make a new array? 'int[][] result=new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];' I tried it but it only gives me the result of another matrix of the same size but with only 0's instead of the right answer...

Comment: Make sure you are not returning the function inside the loop. I have tested the code and it works fine. I have updated the answer, take a look now.

Comment: Yea they look exactly the same. The error is probably somewhere else. I'll find it...thank you for your help though!

Comment: Place some debug code inside the method, print the `scalar` and `matrix` and check whether the input is correct, if it is, you know the error is below that, if not, you know the error must be before the method is called.

Comment: I would but I have no clue what debug code is or how to put it. I'm sorry i'm a total newb. But thanks for trying.

Comment: Simply printing to console is enough: `System.out.println("scalar: "+scalar)`. The matrix though, is a little harder: `System.out.println("matrix: "+Arrays.deepToString(matrix));`